# Calculate Speed using GPS in Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an Android App, which will give me the speed with which I am travelling. Please suggest me some webSites from where I can get some help.

I know there is a function like Location.getSpeed(). But don't know how exactly it works.

Comment: You should find documentation describing how the function is used.  Where have you looked?

Comment: location.setSpeed() not working. You should calculate it like distance/time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First [read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) article to learn how to get GPS fixes.

You can call `getSpeed()` in your location listener, in the onLocationChanged() callback.

Comment: getSpeed() data is always less that the bike top speed.. Eg for 72 KMPH getSpeed showed 65 KMPH

Comment: @PrasannaAnbu could be a GPS chipset issue, please try out with other devices