# Android (get current speed)

Tags: java, android, performance, distance

after getting my distance (using GPS, lat and long), is there any method that I can also get my current speed (using distance and time) , accelerometer are not advised. Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Speed using GPS in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200461/calculate-speed-using-gps-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a start position and an end position and time `dt` which is the time it took to move between the two positions:

```
 float[] distance = new float[2];
 Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude,
     endLatitude, endLongitude, vectorDistance);
 float speed = distance[0]/dt;
```