# Is it possible to track acceleration and speed using gps data?

Tags: android, react-native

Is it possible to track the speed and the acceleration through an android app using the GPS data it provides? I'm planning to create a react native app with these features. But I want to know whether it's possible to do it with the data we can get. Even in native android?

Comment: yes you can get speed= distance/time;

Comment: Use getspeed() in on Locationchangelister like mentioned below

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6200487/7989770

Hope it will help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in pure JS.

For the **speed part** you have the core [React Native Geolocation API](https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation) where you can find the method `watchPosition`. On each position update, an object is returned with the current speed amongst other attributes (location, altitude...).

For the **acceleration part** you have the [react-native-motion-manager](https://github.com/pwmckenna/react-native-motion-manager) library. You can listen to the accelerometer updates and get the acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to track the speed and the acceleration through an
>   android app using the GPS data it provides?

**Answer:** yes

> location.getSpeed() only returns what was set with
>   location.setSpeed(). This is a value that you can set for a location
>   object.

**To calculate the speed using GPS, you'll have to do a little math:**

```
Speed = distance / time
```

**so how to do that**

```
(currentGPSPoint - lastGPSPoint) / (time between GPS points)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each location provided by all LocationProviders has the instant speed at the point where the location was taken, which is unstable and it can differ between devices. The average speed is more precise, you have to calculate distance and time. This is how I calculate distance between 2 locations:

```
static double distance (Location in1, Location in2) {

    double R = 6371000;
    double la1 = in1.getLatitude()* Math.PI/180;
    double la2 = in2.getLatitude()* Math.PI/180;
    double lo1 = in1.getLongitude()* Math.PI/180;
    double lo2 = in2.getLongitude()* Math.PI/180;
    double tmp1 = Math.sin((la1-la2)/2)*Math.sin((la1-la2)/2) + Math.cos(la1)*Math.cos(la2) * Math.sin((lo1-lo2)/2) * Math.sin((lo1-lo2)/2);
    double tmp2 = Math.sqrt(tmp1);
    double d = Math.abs(2 * R * Math.asin(tmp2) * 100000) / 100000;

    return d;
}
```

You can use this function as well, but I'd rather use the other one, which stores the result in "results" :)

```
Location.distanceBetween(in1.getLatitude(),in1.getLongitude(),in2.getLatitude(),in2.getLongitude(),results);
```

So getting the speed in m/s (that's the 1000* for) is quite straightforward:

```
double avgSpeed = 1000 * distance(loc1,loc2) / (loc2.getTime()-loc1.getTime)
```